# npm audit returns Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: npm

I'm running

```
npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

specifiying registry because I'm using a private registry in my project which doesn't support audit. And I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Viraj/.npm/_logs/2022-10-31T08_33_23_876Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot convert undefined or null to object` can occur due to network timeout issue.
[(reference)](https://github.com/InfoSec812/npm-audit-ci-wrapper/issues/57)

I had few packages which were coming from private npm registry, once I uninstalled them (to remove them from audit), I was able to run npm audit without any issues